# How can I create an alert on the subscription level for every new resource created?

Tags: azure, cloud, monitoring, alerts, azure-alerts

I want to get alerts whenever a new resource is created, I tried to do it through the monitor using the activity log but could not find any default configuration which can provide the needful. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Create Event Grid Subcription on Subscription level. Narrow actions to e.g. Successful Writes only, your choice, send such event when its triggered to some external processor (e.g. Azure Function) and do whatever you need with it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a log alert for any create events.

You will first need to stream the activities to log anayltics:
https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/activity-log#send-to-log-analytics-workspace

You can then set a log alert on the subscripition to detect any resource creation.